# android folder lock with api for developers

Tags: android, locking, directory

Are there any folder lock apps of android which provide api to lock a folder through other application? I need to lock a folder(password protected) containing various types of file(flash,video,text) through my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot lock folders in Android.

Folders on internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) are already "locked" insofar as each application has access to only its files.

Folders on external storage cannot be locked -- any application, and the user, can read or write as needed (though apps need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission).

Comment: thank you for the answer.. what is the size limit for internal storage for each application(if there is any)?

Comment: @saurabh: There is no per-application limit.

Answer (score -1):

Folder Lock for android does this work fine. you can use this app, download from play store